# Facebook is not displaying any messages

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

This is how it looks currently:
[image]

When I click on Messages, it dims out and then doesn't display anything. I have tried the following:

- Refreshed the page.
- Tried it in latest versions of Safari, Chrome and Firefox.
- Tried it on different computers.
- Disabled adblocker and similar plugins.
- Send a bug report for over a month ago without any respond.
- Loaded up a picture of Mark Zuckerberg and spat on the screen.

There you go. I know what the issue is. For a great while ago, Facebook introduced something in Messages (where the screen dimmed and you could enter username, phone and similar, or simply choose to skip, I am sure someone remembers this) and since then, I can't get the window to show on my account, to skip those steps... therefore, it is stuck like this.

Comment: Try https://m.facebook.com/messages

Comment: Thanks for sharing that link, while I can access my messages by the mobile site, it is only a desperate solution and not a permanent fix. Cheers regardless.

Comment: Do you have any ad blocker turned on? It seems like Facebook is trying to show a modal window and it's not showing.

Comment: No, as I stated above, I have disabled all plugins, including adblockers, and tried it on different computers and browsers. Same results.

Answer (score 2):

Use this form to report an issue with blank messages.

[Report an Issue with Messages](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/?id=143318592452565)

Answer (score 1):

Try going to `about:config`, filter for storage and set dom local storage to `false`. Things all started working then. It turns off LSO cookies and Facebook has to push out content normally.